# regex not should match digit_

Tags: regex

Im trying to write a regex that does not match a string which ends with digit_

e.g.

```
abc0_@stack.com should return false
```

The regex that i wrote is `'^[a-z0-9\.\+_-]*[0-9_]+@stack.com`
How can i modify this regex so that all the "digit_" is not matched and a false is returned.

The following test cases is what I am trying to match.

```
abc@stack.com         Valid
abc123@stack.com      Valid
abc9_@stack.com       Invalid
abc09@gmail.com       Invalid
```

Comment: What do you mean by `ends`? the `0_` in your example is in the middle of the string...

Comment: if there is 0-9_before the @, the regex pattern match should return false

Comment: It's rare that someone mentions language/tool used by regex...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a negative lookahead based on your current regex:

```
^(?![a-z0-9\.\+_-]*\d_@)
```

This asserts that there is not some (or none) characters in the group `[a-z0-9\.\+_-]` followed by a digit (`\d`), an `_` and an `@` starting from the beginning of the string.

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/xoAYNs/2)

Comment: the regex i wrote is '^[a-z0-9\.\+_-]*(?![\d_])+@stack.com .  but this is giving true for abc0_@stack.com when it should result in false

Comment: @Ravi the regex I wrote does give false for `abc0_@stack.com`, it only matches e.g. `abc0@stack.com`. See the demo...